# Any benefit to uninstalling unused applications?

Tags: 64-bit, 14.10, uninstall, performance, software-uninstall

I am a newcomer to Linux and after a few months of trying out different distros I have now settled on Ubuntu 14.10 on my aging HP TX2000 Notebook.

One thing I am unsure of is if there is any benefit to uninstalling the many apps I will not likely be using.

Being used mainly for web browsing / videos / old school gaming on wine etc. I cant see myself using things like the Libre Office apps for example.

It seems somewhat ingrained in me when using windows or my smartphone to uninstall / disable as many unused applications as possible and I wondered if anyone can let me know if this will result in any system streamlining performance gains in Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well, everytime something you have installed will be updated you will be prompted to download and install updates. But beside that and having more "clutter" I don't think it will have **much** effect. Of course if you have installed some deamons or anything that runs without you explicitely saying so will take some of processing power (perhaps at start)...

Comment: IMO it is easier to start with a minimal install and build up. Removing packages you do not understand can cause breakage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the program we are talking about is not a service (examples of those are mysql, apache) it will not impede on the speed of your system. And even those services tend to be rather quiet when not actively used.

The only benefit you will see is that there is less to update where there are updates. But that is not worth all the trouble tracking down the software you want to uninstall and uninstall it.